# Rasbperry and Xamarin: Bluetooth Low Energy

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.forms, raspberry-pi, bluetooth-lowenergy

I tried to create a little application to detect my Raspberry 3 B with a Xamarin Forms.

So, I used [this](https://github.com/aritchie/bluetoothle) package to use Bluetooth in my app.
As you can see, I only can scan Bluetooth Low Energy devices.

Well, when I use my bluetooth setting in my Android 6, I can see my RPI.
But when I use the sample of the author of the package, I can't see it.

I already opened a issue ticket, and it told me:

> This library supports Bluetooth LE, not standard bluetooth. You need to make sure that your device is broadcasting on BLE.

But, I have lot of difficulties to broadcast on BLE and I don't understand how to do that.

Can you help me?

Thank you.

Comment: If you think a Raspberry Pi 3 running Raspbian will always advertise BLE packets after power on, you are wrong. You need to use software to start advertising (for example BlueZ).

Comment: Yes, it's what I done. Downloaded BlueZ and configurated. But I think I did something wrong :/

Comment: Then you should edit the question so that it contains exactly which steps you have tried.

Comment: @Emil Ok I will edit tomorow because I don't have my rpi here. I'm going to reinstall Raspbian to get clean OS